# Relationship between Riemannian Exponential Map and Lie Exponential Map

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, riemannian-geometry

It is well known that for a matrix Lie group the Lie exponential map is **$e ^z$**. This maps a tangent vector $z$ at the **identity** to a group element.

On the other hand the general Riemannian exponential map centered at point $x$ is given by $\exp _x \triangle$  which maps a tangent vector $\triangle$ at point $x$ (not necessarily identity element) to a group element.

Is there a relationship between these two exponential maps?

For example is below formula correct? If so, are there any conditions involved?

$\exp _x \triangle = xe ^{x^{-1}\triangle}$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Notice that you need to pick a metric on a Lie group for the "general Riemannian exponential map" to be defined.

If you happen to pick an invariant metric on a Lie group, then every geodesic is (locally) a translate of a 1-parameter subgroup (so essentially both exponentials are the same thing)

I don't know what happens if there are no invariant metrics.

Comment: How can there be no invariant metrics?

Comment: @Theo: A Lie group has an invariant metric iff its adjoint group has compact closure in $\operatorname{GL}(\mathfrak g)$.

Comment: Here did you mean either left(/right)-invariant or bi-invariant?

Also is there any online/book material which explains how the relation is achived?

Comment: @sam: I mean bi-invariant. You can find the proof in *Lie groups and compact groups* by John Frederick Price, on googlebooks: I am not familiar with it, but it's what google brings me to.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing up this misconception!

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this more.

Comment: I think the metric on the Lie group must be _bi_-invariant, and the equivalence may fail if the metric is only right (or left) invariant.