# A lower bound estimate for the Left-invariant distance from $g_t$ to $e$ in the Lie group $\text{SL}(d, \mathbb R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G:=\text{SL}(d, \mathbb R)$, a matrix Lie group and let $(g_t)_{t \in \mathbb R}$ be a one-parameter, diagonalizable, unbounded subgroup of the Lie group $\text{SL}(d, \mathbb R)$. Let $d$ be a Left invariance metric on $G$. The general construction is shown in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4151204/967709) and please note that this metric is [not bi-invariant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319789/uniqueness-of-bi-invariant-metrics-on-lie-groups).

I learnt from a paper the following fact: there exists $\alpha>0$ such that

$$d(g_t,e)> \alpha t, \forall t \in \mathbb R.$$

How do we prove this? Or, are there any good references?

One possible approach might be connecting this metric to the hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb H^d$. But I completely don't understand why these two metrics are "equivalent".

For those who want to use exponential maps, please note that the Riemanian exponential map and the Lie exponential map are not the same unless the metric is bi-invariant. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17052/967709).

---

Background information:

The question comes from the bottom of the https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.04082.pdf#page=11#, where $\|g_t\|$ there is our $d(g_t,e)$. See page 10 (before Definition 4.1) of the paper.

Comment: Are you asking something related to this - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668215/is-geodesic-distance-equivalent-to-norm-distance-in-sl-n-mathbbr

Answer (score 1):

are you still interested in this question? Your $g_t$ is of the form $e^{tX}$ for some nonzero diagonal element $X$, right? If you pick your distance function $d$ on $G$ coming from the left-invariant Riemannian metric induced by the Frobenius inner product $(A|B):=\operatorname{Trace}(AB^T)$ on $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$, then the [notes](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ebryant/GroupGeodesicsNotes.pdf) linked in Max's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618472/left-invariant-metric-on-sln-mathbbr/4151204#4151204) say that, since $X$ is symmetric, $f(t):= e^{tX}$ is actually a geodesic on $G$ passing through the identity. From this the equation
\begin{equation}\label{1}\tag{1}
\operatorname{d}(g_t,\operatorname{Id}_G) = \|X\| t
\end{equation}
should be clear for $t$ near $0$, no?

Since $G$ is geodesically complete, we know that for any $t >0$, there is a distance-minimizing geodesic from $\operatorname{Id}_G$ to $e^{tX}$. And, using the notes again, we see that any geodesic starting from $\operatorname{Id}_G$ must have the form
\begin{equation}
h(s) = e^{sY^T}e^{s(Y-Y^T)}\ \text{ for some } Y \in \operatorname{Lie}(G).
\end{equation}

Thus, in order to show that something like \eqref{1} holds (for all times) we must study equations of the form
\begin{equation}\label{2}\tag{2}
e^{sY^T}e^{s(Y-Y^T)} = e^{tX}
\end{equation}
where we assume $Y$ has norm $1$, $s,t>0$ and that $\operatorname{d}(e^{tX},\operatorname{Id}_G)=s$.

In \eqref{2}, the matrix $e^{s(Y-Y^T)}$ is orthogonal so that it has operator norm $1$? The matrix $e^{tX}$ has operator norm $e^{ct}$ for some $c >0$. And we have the estimate on operator norm
\begin{equation}
\|e^{sY^T}\|_{\operatorname{op}} \leq e^{s\|Y^T\|_{\operatorname{op}}} \leq e^{sd\|Y^T\|} = e^{sd}.
\end{equation}
where we used the equivalence of the operator norm with the Frobenius norm  (with explicit constant $d>0$) in the second inequality. Putting these facts together, the equality in \eqref{2} gives us that
\begin{equation}
e^{tc} \leq e^{sd}
\end{equation}
which shows that
\begin{equation}
 tc/d \leq s\ \left(= \operatorname{d}(e^{tX},\operatorname{Id}_G)\right).
\end{equation}

I don't know if what I wrote is correct so please let me know if you see anything weird or fishy.

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ is a left-invariant Riemannian metric on a Lie group $G$, any one-parameter subgroup is parameterized proportional to arclength with respect to $g$.

This follows immediately from the fact that by left-invariance of $g$, left translation by any element $x \in G$ is a Riemannian isometry, and the definition of the Lie group exponential map.

Consequently $d(Id_G, g_t) = t \lVert X \rVert$ where $X$ is the infinitesimal generator of $g_t$. In particular, this gives the lower bound you're looking for.

Note that no hypothesis on diagonalizability of $g_t$ is required, and that this result is *not* the same as asserting that any one-parameter subgroup is a geodesic for the left-invariant metric (which need not be true, if $G$ is not compact)--it is a weaker statement.