# Where can geodesics on $G:=\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ intersect?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, curvature, geodesic

I'm using the Frobenius inner product on $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$; $(A|B):= \operatorname{Trace}(AB^T)$. [These notes](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ebryant/GroupGeodesicsNotes.pdf) show that the geodesics for the induced Riemannian metric (and connection) which start at the identity are of the form
\begin{equation}
e^{sY^T}e^{s(Y-Y^T)}.
\end{equation}
In particular, $e^{tX}$ is a geodesic when $X$ is symmetric.

With respect to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268830/a-lower-bound-estimate-for-the-left-invariant-distance-from-g-t-to-e-in-the/4675234#4675234), consider a situation where $X, Y \in \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ are distinct with $X$ diagonal and $Y$ arbitrary.

**Question 1:** Is it possible that there exist times $s, t>0$ for which
\begin{equation}
e^{sY^T}e^{s(Y-Y^T)}= e^{tX}?
\end{equation}

**Question 2:** If yes to the above, can one describe the situations in which this can happen? (Note that $X$ is assumed to be diagonal). I'm perhaps looking for an answer that contrasts/compares the situation on the sphere where the geodesics emanating from a point $p$ all come together after a fixed time ($\pi R$) at the antopodal point $-p$.

I'm not really familiar with Riemannian geometry but I remember reading something about 'conjugate points' and 'Jacobi vector fields' at some point.